# Truncated tab bar in Qt

Tags: qt, tabs, truncated, qtabbar

On this [site](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html) 
there is a picture with two "tab-systems". 
I would like to have the second one, which is described as "A truncated tab bar shown in the Plastique widget style." There you have arrows, which allow you to slide through the tabs.

I have implented a "tab-system" which looks like this:

```
QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget();

tabWidget->addTab(ToolGroupBox(),"Toolbox");
tabWidget->addTab(CameraGroupBox(),"Camera");
...
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(tabWidget);
```

As I understand it is possible to create the truncated tabs if I use the tabRect-function of the QTabBar-class. I have tried several things but unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [usesScrollButtons](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#usesScrollButtons-prop) property of the `QTabBar`. You can access the `QTabBar` of your `QTabWidget` via the [`tabBar`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#tabBar) method.

You don't need to get involved with `tabRect` at all. The documentation just before the picture of the two tab systems is not directly related to it. The figure is just showing you two possible tab styles.